# Playstation 4 Slim and Sony BDV-N8100W Wifi Issue

Tags: wireless-networking, playstation

I have a PlayStation 4 Slim, latest software update. PS4 is connected wirelessly to Google Wifi. Networking is all good up to this point.

On the same spot, I have a Sony BDV-N8100W (Blu-ray, 5.1 receiver).

If I turn on the Blu-ray, the PS4 Internet slows down to a crawl (~50kbps). If I turn the Blu-ray off, the PS4 network is back to normal.

This is weird, because:

- PS4 Slim is on 5GHz, BR is on 2.4GHz
- PS4 Slim can be on guest Wifi (or BR, vice versa), doesn't help
- BR can have Wifi disconnected, doesn't help

There's no way to turn off Wifi on BR, even though I don't really use the network feature.

The BR comes with rear receiver that's connected wirelessly, proprietary protocol. Maybe this caused an interference with 5GHz Wifi?

Any other pointer that can pinpoint the problem or resolve this Wifi issue?

Comment: Change the frequency of the 2.4 Ghz and 5.0 Ghz.+/-

Comment: That works! If you press option when choosing Wifi SSID, you can filter by frequency. I chose 2.4GHz like the BR and it is stable now.